# JavaScript confirm on blur/focusout event caught in endless loop on some OS's

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

I have [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpe0vLn7/) of a JavaScript confirm box. Here's the snippet as well:

```js
$('#txtTestOne, #txtTestTwo').on('blur', function(e) {
  var retval = confirm('Do you really want to go there?');
  if (!retval) {
    e.target.focus();
  } else {
    e.relatedTarget.focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtTestOne" autofocus>
<input type="text" id="txtTestTwo">
```

This works fine on my laptop (OS X 10.6.8), tested in both Chrome and Opera. However, when I test it on my desktop machine running OS X 10.11.6, I find that the confirm box gets caught in an endless loop, both in Chrome and Safari (keeps re-displaying the window after making a selection).

I added the snippet in as well, to make sure that it wasn't a problem with jsfiddle, and no, it isn't. Same behavior both for the snippet and jsfiddle.

Since the problem exists in two different browsers on one OS, and doesn't in two browsers on another, it seems unlikely that it's a browser issue. I don't think I'm doing anything wrong with the code, either, but one never knows until one knows.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there some sort of problem with the confirm method that I don't know about? Also, if it runs correctly on your machine, perhaps you'll be so kind as to mention in the comments what OS you're running.

Comment: I'm guessing the browsers on your 10.6.8 install are older (10.6 support was dropped at some point), which is probably why they behave differently.

Comment: That is true, but it doesn't explain why the problem only occurs in the newer system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I have found a solution. If you have a clearer picture than I do of why we have to do this, please explain.

```js
$('#txtTestOne, #txtTestTwo').on('blur', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.relatedTarget).is(':text')) {
    return;
  }

  var retval = confirm('Do you really want to go there?');
  if (!retval) {
    e.target.focus();
  } else {
    e.relatedTarget.focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtTestOne" autofocus>
<input type="text" id="txtTestTwo">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go buddy I fixed it. I also had an infinity loop problem using Chrome, but this should now work as you expected in all browsers I hope

```js
$('.input').on('click', function(e) {
  count++;
  var retval = confirm('Do you really want to go there?');
  if (!retval) {
    $('.input').not(e.target).focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtTestOne" class="input" autofocus>
<input type="text" id="txtTestTwo" class="input">
```

Nope sry, blur with focus didn't work, didn't tested it properly

Comment: Interesting, and thanks for taking a shot. But when I put the blur event back in, the problem returns. If I use the click event, then tabbing to the other box doesn't fire it.

Comment: The problem is that the blur event fires up when input element loses it's focus, so on the first switch between inputs everything runs fine, but then we use focus on other input that triggers blur event again and from this point it runs into an infinity

Comment: So I'm afraid, but I guess you can not use them both together, because they will continuously fire up each other

Comment: @BobRodes yes exactly, but you listen for blur event to happen on both inputs and when it happens you change focus depending on if statement. So when focus changes it triggers blur event again because "previous" input lost it's focus

Comment: I don't think it works that way. Once the element loses focus, you can focus on the other element without firing the first element's blur event. Because it's already lost focus. Also, this problem also happens if you select Cancel, which refocuses on the element that lost focus. That being so, there is no other element that loses focus, so I can't see where a blur event could happen.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted and reposted after giving it some more thought. So, what do you say to why the blur event would happen if you select Cancel?